# How to feed large PrefetchDataset to 3d CNN without exhausting memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I'm reading 4D image numpy array saved into hard disk by memory mapping and feeding into tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices along with the target variable. The numpy array size is more than 10 GB. When I go into 3d CNN model training, the kernel dies because of memory exhausting. How to solve this problem?

Below is the partial code:

```
def load_train():
    
    X = np.load('trainX.npy', mmap_mode='c')
    y = np.load('trainY.npy', mmap_mode='c')
    
    return X, y

x_train, y_train = load_train()

def load_val():
    
    X = np.load('testX.npy', mmap_mode='c')
    y = np.load('testY.npy', mmap_mode='c')
    
    return X, y

x_val, y_val = load_val()


train_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
validation_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val))

batch_size = 2

train_dataset = (
    train_loader.shuffle(len(x_train))
    .map(train_preprocessing)
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(2)
)

validation_dataset = (
    validation_loader.shuffle(len(x_val))
    .map(validation_preprocessing)
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(2)
)


def get_model(width=512, height=512, depth=645):

    inputs = keras.Input((width, height, depth, 1))

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(inputs)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Conv3D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(units=512, activation="relu")(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)

    outputs = layers.Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="3dcnn")
    return model

model = get_model(width=512, height=512, depth=645)

model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
    metrics=["acc"],
)

model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I asume by "the kernel dies" you mean your run time crashes since not enough RAM is available.

Since RAM is fixed, you have several options:

1. perform manual garbage collection, by deleting unused objects
2. use a lower precission for representing your data, e.g. float16 instead of float32
3. Instead of loading the entire dataset into RAM at once, use binary streams and load data on demand. Can be optimized by prefetching and interleaving. Here is a detailed guide on how to implement TFRecord binary file streaming: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord

PS: for performance reasons you should first batch your dataset and then apply map() in your input pipeline. In that way you take advantage of victorization and with it the performance of your input puipeline is increased.

Best,
Sascha